# Routing CustomId and Id to same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to setup a routing map that supports something like
"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/**{id}={customid}**"

For example, I have 2 URLs:

`/Home/Index/1`

`/Home/Index?customid=1`

How can I get both of those URLS go to to the same controller?

My current mapping in Startup is pretty simple:

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areaRoute",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    "OnlyAction",
    "{action}/{id?}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

This is the controller I'm trying to get to support both URLs

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetRecords")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRecords(int id)
```

A point in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it's required to perform the `GetRecords(int id)` action when entered either `/Home/Index/1` or `/Home/Index?customid=1` you can add the following attribute to the action method:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetRecords")]
[Route("/Home/Index/{customid?}")]

public async Task<IActionResult> GetRecords(int? customid)
{
   // Place code here to process the request... 
}
```

The `customid` parameter is defined as nullable type `int?` to be able process a default value.

For more information see [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with `/Home/Index` will end up in `GetRecords` with customid equals to `0`, then this should work

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    "GetRecordsFromPath",
    "Home/Index/{customId}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "GetRecords" });
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    "GetRecordsFromQuery",
    "Home/Index",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "GetRecords" });
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRecords(int customid) //id -> customid
```

If not, then you will need somehow to tell aspnet to go to different actions for `Home/Index` and for `Home/Index?customid=1`

##### Upd

You can experiment with `UseRewriter` middleware and have the rule to rewrite `/Home/Index?customid=1` to `/Home/Index/1`.
It can be helpful if you need a different action method for `/Home/Index` or there are more complex scenarios for path and query.

##### Upd 2

This works

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var url = context.Request.Path.Value;

    if (url == "/Home/Index")
    {
        if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("customid"))
        {
            var customid = context.Request.Query["customid"];
            context.Request.Path = $"/Home/Index/{customid}";
        }
    }

    await next();
});
```